# Per Pixel collision detection

Tags: c#, xna, collision

Creating a 2D Hell Theme Helicopter game in XNA.

Having a few problems with my Per Pixel collision detection in that it is returning true when the colours are not colliding.

Here is the code for my Per Pixel:

```
class PPCollisionDetection
{
    public Rectangle rect1, rect2;
    public Color[] data1, data2;

    public PPCollisionDetection()
    {
    }

    public Boolean Detect(Rectangle r1, Rectangle r2, Texture2D t1, Texture2D t2)
    {
        data1 = new Color[t1.Width * t1.Height];
        t1.GetData(data1);
        data2 = new Color[t2.Width * t2.Height];
        t2.GetData(data2);

        rect1 = r1;
        rect2 = r2;

        int top = Math.Max(rect1.Top, rect2.Top);
        int bottom = Math.Min(rect1.Bottom, rect2.Bottom);
        int left = Math.Max(rect1.Left, rect2.Left);
        int right = Math.Min(rect1.Right, rect2.Right);

        for (int y = top; y < bottom; y++)
            for (int x = left; x < right; x++)
            {
                Color colour1 = data1[(x - rect1.Left) +
                                        (y - rect1.Top) * rect1.Width];
                Color colour2 = data2[(x - rect2.Left) +
                                        (y - rect2.Top) * rect2.Width];

                if (colour1.A != 0 && colour2.A != 0)
                   return true;
            }
        return false;
    }
}
```

And here is where I call Detect:

```
if (new Rectangle((int)Helicopter.position.X,(int) Helicopter.position.Y,(int)Helicopter.HelicopterAnimation.Rectangle.Width,(int)Helicopter.HelicopterAnimation.Rectangle.Height).Intersects(stalagtiteRectangle))
{
    if (collDetect.Detect(new Rectangle((int)Helicopter.position.X, (int)Helicopter.position.Y, (int)Helicopter.HelicopterAnimation.Rectangle.Width, (int)Helicopter.HelicopterAnimation.Rectangle.Height), stalagtiteRectangle, Helicopter.HelicopterAnimation.animation,
         stalagtites))
    {
        touched = true;
    }
    else
    {
        touched = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Just a suggestion, to find the overlapped area of two rectangles maybe you should use [Rectangle.Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.rectangle.intersect.aspx)

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: Can you spot any mistakes in my code? It's not working for me! Sorry!

Comment: I think the method is right because I found it several times on Google. Do your textures use the alpha channel? Because if you are using the XNA solid magenta as "transparent" this method won't work. You should debug the code and see what `data1` and `data2` actually contain.

Comment: do you really need pixel collision? rectangle or circle will not work for you? if object is large, you can combine few rectangles to cover it.

Comment: We have oddly shaped stalagmites and stalagmites as the roof and the floor of the game which was the main reason for using Pixel Perfect, We aren't using the XNA solid magenta as transparent, the images actually have a transparent background!

Comment: it should be transparent, because code is checking alpha channel `(colour1.A)` for collision not magneta.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need the first rectangle collision since you're already checking with the per-pixel collision.

And I believe it should be:

```
t1.GetData<Color>(data1);
t2.GetData<Color>(data2);
```

Comment: I don't think so, GetData can get the type from the structure you pass it as parameter, in this case Color[].

Comment: That's what I have it in my Collision class, but you're right, it would get it whether you insert the defined data type or not.

Comment: if he use perfect pixel collsion then he must first do rectange collision. because pixel collision is really expensive, and no need to check pixel collsision if object are not even near eachother.

Comment: It's already checking for the collision, is it not? I've been doing per-pixel collision without the rectangle collision first and it works fine.